# Apps won't close on Huawei MediaPad M5

Tags: applications

Usually on Android, there is a button to show what apps are running the background - this isn't a list of system processes (nor system apps), but user started applications (games). After we press the button to see the list of apps, there is often a button which closes all open apps. This should be familiar to everyone who uses Android!

The problem I have is, my daughter's Hawaei MediaPad running Android Version 8.0.0 doesn't persist the close. When we press the square button, we can see all running apps. If we close each individually or one at a time, return to the home page and then press the square button again, all the apps remain.

I tried with an app called Advanced Task Killer from the Play Store. By clicking boost (which means close apps), a progress bar was displayed showing it was killing each task, but again as soon as I open the list of running apps, instead of seeing an empty list which is what I expected, I see the same list of applications.

The only thing that kills the list is a restart of the machine.

Is there anything we're doing wrong?

**Update**

I've played with this tablet a little more. Some times when I choose to kill all, they all disappear. If I return to the list, it remains empty (great). if I start another app and return to the list, instead of having only that recent app, it is listing all of them!

When I kill the apps, it sometimes shows a message showing how much memory I've freed up.

I also should point out, this machine is my daughters and as such has Family Link. I'm not sure if that has made any impact.

**Edit**

When I say it still running, I mean, with state. If it were a list of recently used apps, then when I clicked on one, I'd expect the application to start (restart). In this case, the application is able to resume.

For example, I open a game and get half way through level 1. I then press the square icon to show all running apps, click the bin icon to shut all running apps. Now, I press the square button again and I can see the list of the recently closed apps. I click on the game, and it resumes from half way through level 1

The game:
[image]

All running apps and the option to close all
[image]

All apps have cleared (apparently)
[image]

Press the square button again and see the apps are still running
[image]

Click the game and note the game is still in progress
[image]

(sorry, with a 2mb limit, I can't upload a 7mb animated gif showing the issue in an animation)

**Edit 2**

Force close does what I expect it to do. It makes the app close. Even though it still appears in the background tasks (I'd guess that's expected), when I click on the app from the list of background tasks, the app starts from the "beginning", it does not resume. This means, I have a work around but this is not ideal.

Comment: You do not confuse the list of *last recently used* apps with "currently running", do you?

Comment: That is a great question @Izzy, how would I know? I'm suspecting currently running because when I click on any, it returns me the application or game. If it was recently used, I would suspect it to have to load the game/intro  from the start and we'd see the applications splash screen etc

Comment: To give you a clue: How do you get to that list? Via a bunch of menues (like *Settings › Apps*  and select "Running") – or by the simple tap on a button below your screen? The latter is "recently used" (and from your description this seems what you are referring to: a button next to the home button?), the former is "running". And Task-Killers are not for freeing space – but just to stop malfunctioning apps that cannot be stopped otherwise.

Comment: Ah... It may well be recently used! I wonder why then, after I click it, it tells me how much memory it has freed up :S @Izzy

Comment: I have the exact same problem! It's not you, I'm in IT, it's not like I don't know what I'm doing. The only thing I'm not sure about, it's whether it's due to the fact that it's a managed account using Family Link, for my son, and I noticed that in your case it's also for your daughter. Maybe that is the problem? I cannot install Google Play either on this tablet for the same reason. Did you find a solution?

Comment: My youngest daughter is now old enough for a tablet. She is on family link, set up same way. No issues with her Lenovo tablet....

Comment: What happens when you go to System > Apps > select your app and force close it?

Comment: Force close does that I expect it to do. It makes the app close. Even though it still appears in the background tasks (I'd guess that's expected), when I click on the app from the list of background tasks, the app starts from the "beginning", it does not resume.

Comment: Usually there is an X to remove apps from Recent apps list. Your device doesn't have one? You can also swipe the listed apps left or right (or both depending on the device) to remove them from the list.

Comment: Swiping and the x does the same thing

Comment: There is some applications that have some services that persists even if the app is closed. Theses services will listen for different actions as when the device started or a service that receive push notifications even if the app is closed. 
I suggest using ADB to check that. If you need more information how to do that, I will create a community wiki as answer.

Comment: Sorry but what is ADB?

Comment: Android Debug Bridge is a tool to connect to the phone using USB with the PC.

Answer (score 0):

The applications that are available on the Play Store will not kill Apps as they use the permission GET_TASK which is deprecated from API 26 (Android 5.0) and there is no equivalent for recent Android versions unless if it's a system App (came installed with the phone not from the Play Store).

The solutions to kill the background app is to use an app that came with Huawei system or simply use developers options which can let you kill the background services and processes.

For the second solution, please follow the steps bellow:

1. Go to Settings > System > About phone on your phone.
2. Keep tapping Build number until the message "You are already a developer" is displayed.
3. Go to Settings > System > Developer options > Running services.

You can find a list of third party apps running services. You can click on the App that you want to kill then select "Stop" this will definitely kill the app until you open it again. If the wanted App does not appear in the list you can click on "SHOW CACHED PROCESS" (Top right corner which is not recommended unless you know what are you doing) and it will list all the services and processes.

References:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#GET_TASKS
- https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/quickapp-open-developer-option